# jQuery datepicker with datatable (date range inclusive issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker on my website for a range value, which works fine apart from a small issue with the max date not being inclusive.

Note: I am using datepicker with jQuery datatables. Datatable date columns returns the date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ss:mm` format.

If I select the start date as `2018-02-25` and end date as `2018-02-27` the datatable only returns the records from `2018-02-25` until `2018-02-26`, whereas I would like to return the records for `2018-02-27` as well.

html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control dateStart" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD (Start Date)">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control dateEnd" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD (End Date)">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-MM-DD');

    var oTable = $('#data-table').DataTable();

    $('.dateStart').click(function() {
        $(".dateStart").datepicker("show");
    });

    $('.dateEnd').click(function() {
        $(".dateEnd").datepicker("show");
    });

    $(".dateStart").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        "onSelect": function(date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.draw();
        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.draw();
    });

    $(".dateEnd").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        "onSelect": function(date) {
            maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.draw();
        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.draw();
    });

    // Date range filter
    minDateFilter = "";
    maxDateFilter = "";

    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
                aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
            }

            if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
                if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
                if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Script reads 2018-02-27 as 2018-02-27 00:00:00.

You have to set **2018-02-28** instead of 2018-02-27 if you'd like to inlcude 2018-02-27. (Or 2018-02-27 23:59:59)

You can add following line to add a day.

```
maxDateFilter.setDate(maxDateFilter.getDate()+1);
```

Comment: Where should I add that line? I would like to avoid setting 2018-02-28 to include 2018-02-27. Also, I would like the script to read 2018-02-27 as 2018-02-27 23:59:59.

Comment: Try like this:

maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
maxDateFilter.setDate(maxDateFilter.getDate()+1);

Comment: I am getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: maxDateFilter.getDate is not a function`